# Как убрать дубли страниц в WordPress?

Tags: wordpress, seo, woocommerce

Есть магазин на Woocommerce. В панель вебмастеров Google регулярно приходят уведомления о том, что найдены дублирующиеся title и description. Смотрим, что там за дубли - скриншот:

[image]

Выходит, что один и тот же товар доступен по правильному URL (тот, что длиннее) и по URL, 
который не включает главную категорию (в данном случае /ventilyatory/).
И такие дубли обнаруживаются постоянно. Перенаправления проставлены, но проблема остается.

Как предупредить такое дублирование?

WordPress 4.1, тема Virtue, Woocommerce 2.4.7

Answer (score 1):

Обычно в плагинах интернет магазинов товар реализуется в виде стандартной записи WordPress. А, такая запись по умолчанию доступна по "короткой" ссылке. В случае ЧПУ: `URL_сайта+текст_ЧПУ_статьи`.

Исправить ситуацию можно, например, запретив короткие ссылки в настройках WordPress. Для этого в `"Настройки"->"Постоянные ссылки"` выбрать `"Произвольно"` и задать в текстовом поле нужный формат.

Если данный способ не поможет, можно попробовать поработать с robots.txt

Comment: Данный плагин для интернет-коммерции вводит тип записи "товар". Про короткие ссылки в курсе, но это явно не она

Comment: Короткие ссылки в WP имеют вид    http://адрес_домена/?p=1030

Comment: Слово "короткой" не случайно написано в кавычках. А, ещё в ответе есть примечание "в случае ЧПУ".

Comment: Согласен. Но обратите внимание на разницу между URL - не хватает всего-то главной категории, муть какая-то

Comment: У вас на сайте где-то есть эта короткая ссылка. Исправьте ее и гуголь через время перестанет ругаться.